# UpdateFormDigest not always working

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

We have a SharePoint Online site with a list (called PEP) where the EditForm is in classic SharePoint and customised with a WebPart that loads an HTML file witch itself loads some JavaScript code.

When a user edit an existing PEP, we have a mecanish that will insert a record in another list (LockPEP) in the JS code to make sure the user has the exclusivity. That works well when inserting that item in LockPEP.

Problem arise when the user exit the PEP. At that moment we need to remove the LockPEP item. When the user completes his work within 20 minutes that's fine, but when it take more time we start having LockPEP that fail to be removed.

After adding more logs to the application I realised that we have this particular error.

> The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again

That error is cause by an expired __REQUESTDIGEST on the page. As you can see we try to update the request digest before removing the lock (with updateSharePointFormDigest) but that doesn't work all the time. We tried to refresh the form digest automatically every _spFormDigestRefreshInterval ms (witch is 24 minutes) and it seems to help, but we still have issues.

I spent way too much time already trying to fix this thing. I would greatly appreciate some expert advices here.

Here is the code for removing the lock:

```
function updateSharePointFormDigest() {
    console.debug("**updateSharePointFormDigest");

    console.debug("****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: " + $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val());
    UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);
    console.debug("****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: " + $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val());
}

function removeLock() {
    if (!useLocking()) {
        return false;
    }

    console.debug("**removeLock");

    if (lockFormId > 0) {
        updateSharePointFormDigest();

        var deleteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LockPEP')/items(" + lockFormId + ")";

        console.debug("****removeLock right before ajax call lockFormId:" + lockFormId);

        $.ajax({
            url: deleteURL,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                "IF-MATCH": "*"
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.debug("****removeLock ajax beforeSend");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.debug("****removeLock ajax success");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("****removeLock ajax Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
                console.error("****removeLock ajax Text Status: " + textStatus);
                console.error("****removeLock ajax XMLHttpRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest);
                console.error("****removeLock ajax XMLHttpRequest.responseText" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });

        console.debug("****removeLock right after ajax call");
    }
}
```

Console log after running for few hours:

```
14:27:29.012 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1036 **applySecurityForEmployee
14:50:03.183 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installing odsp-web-prod_2023-12-29.005...
14:50:03.199 spserviceworker.js:149 168 installing STS service worker @ odsp-web-prod_2023-12-29.005
14:50:08.536 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: STS (5.34s)
14:50:25.549 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: SPHome (17.01s)
14:50:33.292 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: SitePages (7.74s)
14:50:35.096 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: Embed (1.80s)
14:50:35.104 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: CreateGroup (0.00s)
14:50:35.393 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: SingleWebPart (0.29s)
14:50:39.708 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: VivaHome (4.31s)
14:50:42.876 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: VivaAmplify (3.17s)
14:50:45.722 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: BrokerLogon (2.85s)
14:50:46.183 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: Clipchamp (0.46s)
14:50:47.176 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Installed controller: MeeBridge (0.99s)
14:50:48.237 spserviceworker.js:149  Event handler of 'message' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.
14:50:48.238 spserviceworker.js:149 45207 activating STS service worker @ odsp-web-prod_2023-12-29.005
14:50:48.505 spserviceworker.js:25 [Router] Idle.
14:51:21.680 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1750 **updateSharePointFormDigest
14:51:21.680 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1752 ****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x134BC1FE8864395CEFF0CD76F34D661F1D00646CD0D2B34D60766004D4BC5D3FBBD9B6ABA92321C13374980BECE8EFCC372C70F6FDAF69DA16C597436B9013FD,10 Jan 2024 19:27:18 -0000
14:51:21.953 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1754 ****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x62F38AACBB5B66C807E9FFD7A14ACBBF8C7A72925A1094B4A9E6CD6296AD28805D68C10CB59A56CDC88DD20EDD307290613770C461D360ED7C0E6CB1EC9AF0DD,10 Jan 2024 19:51:21 -0000
14:51:21.953 epedNewForm.js?v=502:27 [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 283ms
15:15:21.685 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1750 **updateSharePointFormDigest
15:15:21.685 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1752 ****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x62F38AACBB5B66C807E9FFD7A14ACBBF8C7A72925A1094B4A9E6CD6296AD28805D68C10CB59A56CDC88DD20EDD307290613770C461D360ED7C0E6CB1EC9AF0DD,10 Jan 2024 19:51:21 -0000
15:15:21.685 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1754 ****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x62F38AACBB5B66C807E9FFD7A14ACBBF8C7A72925A1094B4A9E6CD6296AD28805D68C10CB59A56CDC88DD20EDD307290613770C461D360ED7C0E6CB1EC9AF0DD,10 Jan 2024 19:51:21 -0000
15:39:21.689 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1750 **updateSharePointFormDigest
15:39:21.691 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1752 ****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x62F38AACBB5B66C807E9FFD7A14ACBBF8C7A72925A1094B4A9E6CD6296AD28805D68C10CB59A56CDC88DD20EDD307290613770C461D360ED7C0E6CB1EC9AF0DD,10 Jan 2024 19:51:21 -0000
15:39:22.238 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1754 ****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x7AE7C1D5BA5EFBF378E917B7F9006AD1EF9D82C992CEA65C903322D45068CB1BC9B188E6D7AC200922CA9292AFFBF6A5A3A593A4C28B8A71C8D40C3D3D544329,10 Jan 2024 20:39:22 -0000
15:39:22.238 epedNewForm.js?v=502:27 [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 550ms
16:04:00.706 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1750 **updateSharePointFormDigest
16:04:00.706 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1752 ****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x7AE7C1D5BA5EFBF378E917B7F9006AD1EF9D82C992CEA65C903322D45068CB1BC9B188E6D7AC200922CA9292AFFBF6A5A3A593A4C28B8A71C8D40C3D3D544329,10 Jan 2024 20:39:22 -0000
16:04:01.822 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1754 ****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0xC1DE006C77484D9F0BF508382A0D0D9B1743A36C6D48599BAEF20DE383AFA3130BCDEFD98C3D6BC79EF45C331983027BD89E39E197E00DE66A79E9E4F782BC40,10 Jan 2024 21:04:01 -0000
16:04:01.822 epedNewForm.js?v=502:27 [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 1117ms
16:28:00.718 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1750 **updateSharePointFormDigest
16:28:00.719 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1752 ****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0xC1DE006C77484D9F0BF508382A0D0D9B1743A36C6D48599BAEF20DE383AFA3130BCDEFD98C3D6BC79EF45C331983027BD89E39E197E00DE66A79E9E4F782BC40,10 Jan 2024 21:04:01 -0000
16:28:00.720 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1754 ****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0xC1DE006C77484D9F0BF508382A0D0D9B1743A36C6D48599BAEF20DE383AFA3130BCDEFD98C3D6BC79EF45C331983027BD89E39E197E00DE66A79E9E4F782BC40,10 Jan 2024 21:04:01 -0000
16:52:00.723 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1750 **updateSharePointFormDigest
16:52:00.724 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1752 ****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0xC1DE006C77484D9F0BF508382A0D0D9B1743A36C6D48599BAEF20DE383AFA3130BCDEFD98C3D6BC79EF45C331983027BD89E39E197E00DE66A79E9E4F782BC40,10 Jan 2024 21:04:01 -0000
16:52:01.096 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1754 ****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x187C103F587AD46869B9B0369AEF28991196374BA065328C056A328D3DE1A3B961EEEFF2258A321A557F04186A1794DD8CA662A553ED23AA20723B302D153FEB,10 Jan 2024 21:52:01 -0000
16:52:01.096 epedNewForm.js?v=502:27 [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 373ms
17:16:00.730 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1750 **updateSharePointFormDigest
17:16:00.730 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1752 ****updateSharePointFormDigest before UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x187C103F587AD46869B9B0369AEF28991196374BA065328C056A328D3DE1A3B961EEEFF2258A321A557F04186A1794DD8CA662A553ED23AA20723B302D153FEB,10 Jan 2024 21:52:01 -0000
17:16:00.730 epedNewForm.js?v=502:1754 ****updateSharePointFormDigest after UpdateFormDigest __REQUESTDIGEST: 0x187C103F587AD46869B9B0369AEF28991196374BA065328C056A328D3DE1A3B961EEEFF2258A321A557F04186A1794DD8CA662A553ED23AA20723B302D153FEB,10 Jan 2024 21:52:01 -0000
```

As you can see in the log there are many times where the __REQUESTDIGEST was not updated (log before and after the update). I suspect when the request digest isn't updated it's when the lock fails to get removed. I'll try to get to the buttom of it and update my post with more details.